# No me llega la informacion del formulario al correo

Tags: php, html, formularios, email, mail

tengo un formulario conectado a una base de datos que funciona correctamente, pero cuando voy a enviar los datos al correo no me llega nada, soy nuevo en programación por favor ayúdenme, Gracias. Aqui les dejo el codigo php

```
<?php
require_once("conexion.php");
if (isset($_POST["enviar"])) {
  $nombres = $_POST['nombres'];
  $apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
  $sql = "INSERT INTO contactos (Nombres,Apellidos,Email,Telefono) VALUES ('$nombres', '$apellidos', '$email', '$telefono')";
  mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

  $headers = 'From: ' . $email . " \r\n";
  $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . " \r\n";
  $headers .= "Mime-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain";

  $mensaje = "Este mensaje fue enviado por " . $nombres . $apellidos . ",\r\n";
  $mensaje .= "Su correo es: " . $email . " \r\n";
  $mensaje .= "Mensaje: hola";
  $mensaje .= "Enviado el " . date('d/m/Y', time());

  $para = 'camilotorresvillada@gmail.com';
  $asunto = 'Mensaje de mi sitio web';

  @mail($para, $asunto, $mensaje, $header);
    echo '<script>alert (" Datos enviados correctamente.\n Gracias por contactarnos ");</script>';
    echo '<script>window.location="../index.html"</script>';
} else {
    echo '<script>alert ("Los datos no se pudieron enviar, intentalo de nuevo ");</script>';
}

?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué muestra tu código en pantalla? ¿Revisaste la carpeta SPAM del correo electrónico al que estás enviando el email?

Comment: si ya revise el spam pero nada, y no se muestra ningún error en pantalla. Olvide decir que el formulario esta en hosting gratuito (000webhost), no se si el codigo tiene algun error o toca configurar algo de 000webhost para que se envie